# Why does installing JAX with Docker create such a large image?

Tags: linux, docker, jax

I am trying to `pip install` JAX using Docker and I found that using it just blows up the size of Docker image. The size of image currently is 4.82 GB.

I made sure to bypass caching while installing packages by doing `--no-cache-dir`. While that did reduce the size, the size is still unreasonable huge.

Here is my Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libosmesa6-dev \
    sudo \
    wget \
    curl \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    g++

ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"

RUN mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
RUN bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
RUN rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
RUN ~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
RUN conda init

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

This is how I built it -

```
docker build -t tbd_jax .
```

When I do `docker images`, I get this -

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
tbd_jax      latest    812292e2264e   7 minutes ago    4.82GB
```

After doing `docker history --no-trunc tbd_jax:latest` -

```
SIZE      COMMENT
sha256:812292e2264e4340b7715956824055d7409f9546f8dfa54ccad1da056febf300   8 minutes ago    RUN |1 PATH=/root/miniconda3/bin:/root/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html # buildkit   3.54GB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
```

Is there something I can do to reduce the size? I am a bit of a Docker and Linux newbie so pardon my slowness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `jax[cuda12_pip]` installs all the cuda drivers listed [here](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/jax-v0.4.23/setup.py#L128-L138):

```py
'cuda12_pip': [
  ...
  "nvidia-cublas-cu12>=12.2.5.6",
  "nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12>=12.2.142",
  "nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12>=12.2.140",
  "nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12>=12.2.140",
  "nvidia-cudnn-cu12>=8.9",
  "nvidia-cufft-cu12>=11.0.8.103",
  "nvidia-cusolver-cu12>=11.5.2",
  "nvidia-cusparse-cu12>=12.1.2.141",
  "nvidia-nccl-cu12>=2.18.3",
```

These nvidia driver packages are quite large: for example the `nvidia_cublas_cu12` wheel is over 400MB, and `nvidia-cudnn-cu12` is over 700MB. You may be able to do better by setting up your docker image with system-native CUDA & CUDNN drivers, installed via `apt`. You can find a description of the requirements [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#pip-installation-gpu-cuda-installed-locally-harder). You can also use NVIDIA's pre-defined GPU containers, as mentioned [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#docker-containers-nvidia-gpu).